# Decrypting a string knowing both the encrypted string and the password used to encrypt the string

Tags: encryption, pseudocode

If I have an encrypted string and the password used to encrypt this string but do not have the encryption method, would it be possible to decrypt the string?

---

For example I am given string

`02061258adfa677fa1655f8993c4e35f`

And I am told that the password is

`password`

But I am not told what the encryption method is (In this example it is Blowfish-Compact)

How would I figure out that the decrypted string is

`Example String`

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Assume that the encryption method is custom made for this example.

Comment: This question is best addressed on crypto.stackexchange.com which specializes in these kinds of problems (and probably already has an answer for you). It's off-topic for SO because it doesn't apply to any particular implementation.

Comment: In fact: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12480/guessing-encryption-algorithm-based-on-key-and-ciphertext/12481#12481. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-it-possible-to-derive-the-encryption-method-from-encrypted-text/138#138